# How can i move search results onto a specific page?

Tags: search

I was wondering if it is possible to have the wordpress search results displayed on a different page?

At the moment they are displayed on `http://www.mysite.com/?s=searchterm` but I would like them displayed on my **search-results** template page, so `http://www.mysite.com/search/?s=searchterm`.

Is this possible?

Any help greatly appreciated, S.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You created a page with the slug `search` to "capture" that URL, but WordPress by default already uses that URL for search results. So you were "lucky" that this worked for you, and this is the reason [the redirect supermethod mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/how-can-i-move-search-results-onto-a-specific-page/9970#9970) will work.

So, instead of creating a "fake" page to hold the template, you should just rename the template to `search.php`, [like tnorthcutt suggested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/how-can-i-move-search-results-onto-a-specific-page/9971#9971). If you still want to have content from the page defined in the admin area, I suggest you rename this page and get it via `get_posts()` or another method, because the main loop will contain search results, not this specific page.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem similar recently where the search results were going to the root rather than the `/blog/` slug where I actually wanted the results displayed. I solved it by creating `searchform.php` and simply wrote a custom search template:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/blog/' ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The secret is in the `<?php echo home_url( '/blog/' ); ?>` bit. By default wordpress will resolve to the home directory, like this `<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>`. So all you have to do is specify which directory you want your search results to display. If `searchform.php` exists in your theme it will use that. If not it will use the default form included in the wordpress core functions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may just need to rename your template page. Try creating a `search.php` template file: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Search_Results_.28search.php.29

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin (or read the source too see how the redirect is done - its only a few lines of code).

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nice-search/