# Combine internal search with Google custom search?

Tags: search

I currently have a search box in my sites header, (on every page), which sends the search query to a page called 'Search', which uses a template called `searchpage`. The page/template uses Google custom search to display the results.

Now this all works great, but I would like to use the built-in WordPress search to also return search results on the same page, above the Google results. Effectively using 1 search box to return 2 sets of results on the same page; 1 for WordPress and 1 for Google custom search.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i move search results onto a specific page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/how-can-i-move-search-results-onto-a-specific-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard search results can also be formatted with a theme file, by default `search.php`. You don't need to create a "fake" page for that.

If you don't include any content from the page, and only use the theme file, you can just rename `searchpage.php` to `search.php` and it will work. If you do have some content that comes from a page written in the admin area, then you will have to query for this yourself (using `get_posts()` or another way), because the standard loop will only contain the search results, not that specific page.

So if you want to add the internal WordPress search results to the page, just add a classic loop at the top, and this should display the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Google Custom Search Engine
Replace your searchform with this code:

```
<form action="http://your.blog.url/index.php?s=" id="cse-search-box" class="searchform">  
  <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="your_CSE_ID" />  
  <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />  
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />  
  <label for="q">Search</label>  
  <input type="hidden" name="s" id="s" value="" />  
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="keyword" />  
</form>  
<script>  
  jQuery('#q').bind('change', function() {  
    jQuery(this).val(function(i, val) {  
      jQuery('#s').val(val);  
      return val;  
    });  
  });  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=de"></script>
```

Use this code for the searchresults (after displaying the internal results):

```
<div id="cse-search-results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
  var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
  var googleSearchFrameWidth = 600;
  var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
  var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

There's also the [Google Custom Search plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-custom-search/)